# How can I implement authentication and authorization in a Django REST API using JSON Web Tokens (JWT)?

Tags: django, jwt

I am building a Django REST API and I want to add authentication and authorization to it. I have researched and found that JSON Web Tokens (JWT) is a popular solution for this purpose. However, I am having trouble implementing it in my Django API. Can someone please provide a step-by-step guide or code example on how to implement JWT authentication and authorization in a Django REST API? Thank you in advance for your help.

I tried to implement JWT authentication and authorization in my Django REST API following several online tutorials and articles. I installed the necessary packages, such as Django Rest Framework JWT and PyJWT, and attempted to follow the provided code examples to configure my API for JWT authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for simplicity, I can recommend using a `djoser` package (https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

It has a lot of user based functionallity, but what you looking is rest-framework-simplejwt integration here (it requires `rest_framework_simplejwt` package installed): https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication_backends.html#json-web-token-authentication

Docs on how to use API is here: https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jwt_endpoints.html